# How to wait the return of a future function inside a for loop?

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I wait for the return of a async function in Dart/Flutter during the loop which is in a sync method?

```dart
myMapVar.forEach((key, val) {
  var title = '';

  decideTitle(key).then((val) {
    title = val;
  });

  print(title);
});
```